# I want to know the grammatical errors in this sentence if any. The sentence is:-. "The hospital's construction will be finishing soon."

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context, future-continuous, irrealis-mood

I am confused whether the sentence will be the above mentioned one or should be written like :- The construction of hospital will be ending soon

Answer (score 1):

"The hospital's construction..." is fine.

If you want to re-arrange it to "The construction of hospital" then you still need the definite article: "the construction of the hospital..."

Comment: I would prefer _finishing_ because it conveys the idea of a task being completed. _Ending_ could suggest that the construction was going to stop before the hospital was complete.

Comment: But is the thing "will be finishing " grammatically correct

Comment: Sounds fine to me.